# SyncAdapter using ~10 kb data even when onPerformSync() is empty?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I implemented a periodic sync adapter into my app with a stub authenticator and content provider following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). Upon studying my data usage amounts of my app via settings, it seems that the sync adapter uses an overhead of ~10 kb of data each sync even after I removed all code from onPerformSync(). This is undesirable as that is often larger than the actual amount of data that I want to sync. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can get rid of/minimize it? As I said, I don't need/use all the account/autheticator/content provider stuff, I just need the sync adapter to wake up my service and execute my own sync code.

EDIT: Looks like the settings monitor is just inaccurate. I used TrafficStats and the readings now seem correct. However, that is another problem as I don't want users to look at the settings reading and think I am using data that I am not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that this is what happens? I would suggest to write a new empty app with stub account/content provider and see the result.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you use `TrafficStats` directly, rather than relying on Settings UI.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the settings monitor is just inaccurate. However, that is another problem as I don't want users to look at the settings reading and think I am using data that I am not. Any suggestions?